# User uploads with nginx and docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a `Django` app where users can upload files containing data they want to be displayed in the app. The app is containerised using docker. In production I am trying to configure nginx to make this work and as far as I can tell it is working to some extent.

As far as I can tell the file does actually get uploaded as I can see it in the container, and I can also download it from the app. The problem I am having is that once the form has been submitted it is supposed to redirect to another form, where the user can assign stuff to the data in the app (not really relevant to the question). However, I am getting a 500 error instead.

I have taken a look at the nginx error logs and I am seeing:

```
[info] 8#8: *11 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

and

```
[info] 8#8: *14 client timed out (110: Operation timed out) while waiting for request, client: 192.168.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

when the operation is performed.

I also want the media files to be persisted so they are in a docker volume.

I suspect the first log message may be the culprit but is there a way to prevent this from happening, or is it just a poor connection on my end?

Here is my nginx conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size  52;

    client_body_buffer_size 1M;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    gzip  on;

    upstream app {
        server django:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name dali.vpt.co.uk;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name dali.vpt.co.uk;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;

        location / {
            # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
            try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
        }

        # cookiecutter-django app
        location @proxy_to_app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_pass   http://app;
        }

        location /media/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /app/tdabc/media/;
        }

    }

}
```

and here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_backups: {}
  production_media: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: production_django:0.0.1
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - production_media:/app/tdabc/media
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    command: /start.sh

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: production_postgres:0.0.1
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - production_postgres_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nginx/Dockerfile
    image: production_nginx:0.0.1
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
        - production_media:/app/tdabc/media
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
```

Any help or insight into this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

**Update**
Another thing that I should mention is that when I run the app with my production settings but set `DEBUG` to True it works perfectly but this is only happening when DEBUG is set to false.

Comment: I guess you're using `django-cookiecutter` as template. Hm, what is the value of `MEDIA_URL` in `config.settings.production.py`?

Comment: Yes I am. MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: @Satevg The actual file upload is working. I can see this when I go into the nginx docker container and check the folder, the file I selected to upload is there. It's just that I am getting a 500 error response when it should be a 302 redirect.

Comment: A 500 response would indicate that the Django app has fallen over. What does the Django container log say?

Comment: The django app is being run with gunicorn and it there is no error logged at that point as far as I can see

Comment: Actually have dug a little deeper I think it may be caused by gunicorn closing the connection early but I can't seem to find a way around this.